# Фреймворки для адаптивного пользовательского интерфейса

Tags: интерфейс, adaptive

Ищу информацию для своей научной работы и попал в тупик. Хотел бы узнать, существуют ли на данный момент фреймворки, которые предоставляют разработку адаптивных пользовательских интерфейсов. Речь не идёт о адаптации разметки интерфейса, например, при помощи CSS и т.д, а конкретно о функциональности интерфейса. Например при помощи user based model, когда основываясь на каких-то знаниях или способностях пользователя интерфейс может менять расположение элементов, скрывать ненужные для него элементы и т.д. Или всё таки на данный момент таких решений нет?

Comment: Мне на ум не приходит ничего кроме как когда некоторые приложения при первом запуске спрашивают как им лучше выглядеть: темная/светлая тема, шрифт побольше или поменьше, меньше/больше подсказок и т.д. но это настолько индивидуальные штуки для конкретного приложения, что фрэймворк сразу заточенный под это я себе плохо представляю. Еще часто делают настраиваемые виджеты на главном экране, но это вручную как правило